# Why customs types doesn't appears in configurations file (app.exe.config)?

Tags: c#, configuration-files, typeconverter

Hey guy I've a doubt about C# configuration EXE file.

I want to map my custom settings with my application allowing the user to edit the app.exe.config directly.

I'll show a example to be clearer.

If I put this settings (using the grid view designer):

```
Name TaxaMutacaoPercent
Type Double
Scope Application
Value 10
```

This is what I get in my app.exe.config:

```
<Gth.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="TaxaMutacaoPercent" serializeAs="String">
                <value>10</value>
            </setting>
</Gth.Properties.Settings>
```

But if I make the same with a Custom Type:

```
Name rbis
Type Mensurador
Scope Application
Value 2,1,true,3,true,1.5
```

I don't know where this is stored.

I don't understand what the difference between the standards and customs types about that. Any one can explain it to me?

Obs: My custom Type works pretty well, I can properly store and restore value from my Settings.